# Can you recommend a CSS stylesheet that formats C# code?

Tags: c#, css, code-formatting

I'm working on a code generation tool where the output is display in a  tag and wondered if anyone knew of a CSS stylesheet that would format the output.  My rendering engine is Javascript based and I'd like to continue perform all operations of rendering client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript isn't client side?  Or am I not understanding your question?

you may want to look at [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), which, if I remember correctly, is what StackOverflow uses

Comment: Thanks Neil - Prettify will do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

You could take a look at http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter . It is web based, open source, and uses separate CSS style sheets for formatting and highlighting. Not sure if it is exactly what you want, but maybe worth a look.